# Update dataframe from another dataframe

Tags: r, join, dataframe

I have 2 tables, "transactions" with over 500M rows and "Customers" over 3M rows

```
data <- data.frame(Trans = c(1,2,3,4,5), Cust01 = c("A","B","C","D","F"),
                   Cust02 = c("S","E","","TE","F"), Cust03 = c("F","","D","","F"))

cust_type <-data.frame(Cust = c("A","B","C","D"), Type = c("1","2","3","4"))

dataresult <- data.frame(Trans = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                         Cust01 = c("A","B","C","D","F"), 
                         Cust01Type = c("1","2","3","4","5"),
                         Cust02 = c("S","E","","TE","F"), 
                         Cust02Type = c("","","","",""),
                         Cust03 = c("F","","D","","F"),
                         Cust03Type = c("","","4","",""))
```

I would like to add the customer type to the data in an efficient way. Normally with `sql` I will use multiple left join, I tried that with `dplyr` but takes forever. I also tried to use `%in%` with logic return and then a loop just to focus on the true values. 
Does someone know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want fast performance, nothing beats the `data.table` package (yet). As your transaction data are now in wide format, the first step to do is convert it to long format. This will make it easier to process.

```
library(data.table) #v1.9.5
trans_data <- melt(setDT(data), id.vars = "Trans",
                   variable.name = "Cust",               # set name variable column
                   variable.factor = TRUE,               # set as a factor variable instead of a character variable
                   value.name = "Cvalue")[!Cvalue==""]   # set name value column & remove empty cases
```

When you have done that, you can join the two datatables:

```
# set the keys by which you are joining
setDT(trans_data, key = "Cvalue")
setDT(cust_type, key = "Cust")

# join the customer type into the transaction data
trans_data[cust_type, Ctype:=Type]
```

this gives:

> ```
> > trans_data
>     Trans   Cust Cvalue Ctype
>  1:     1 Cust01      A     1
>  2:     2 Cust01      B     2
>  3:     3 Cust01      C     3
>  4:     4 Cust01      D     4
>  5:     3 Cust03      D     4
>  6:     2 Cust02      E    NA
>  7:     5 Cust01      F    NA
>  8:     5 Cust02      F    NA
>  9:     1 Cust03      F    NA
> 10:     5 Cust03      F    NA
> 11:     1 Cust02      S    NA
> 12:     4 Cust02     TE    NA
> ```

If you want to change the order in the resulting `data.table`, you can do that with for example:

```
setorder(trans_data, Trans, Cust)
```

or all at once with:

```
trans_data <- trans_data[cust_type, Ctype:=Type][order(Trans,Cust)]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > trans_data
>     Trans   Cust Cvalue Ctype
>  1:     1 Cust01      A     1
>  2:     1 Cust02      S    NA
>  3:     1 Cust03      F    NA
>  4:     2 Cust01      B     2
>  5:     2 Cust02      E    NA
>  6:     3 Cust01      C     3
>  7:     3 Cust03      D     4
>  8:     4 Cust01      D     4
>  9:     4 Cust02     TE    NA
> 10:     5 Cust01      F    NA
> 11:     5 Cust02      F    NA
> 12:     5 Cust03      F    NA
> ```