# Replacing a variable name in data1 with the value of Column2 in Data2 when the variable name in Data1 is identical to the value of Column1 in Data2

Tags: r

I am a R beginner. I have two datasets like

```
df1 <- t(data.frame(seq(1,6,by=1),seq(6,1,by=-1)))    
colnames(df1) <- c("ZZZ","YYY","CCC","DDD","XXX","KKK")    
rownames(df1) <- c("a","b")    
Vector1<-c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF")
Vector2<-c("a", "b", "e", "f", "k", "l")
df2<-data.frame(cbind(Vector1, Vector2))
```

df1 is

```
   ZZZ  YYY  CCC  DDD  XXX  KKK
a    1    2    3    4    5    6
b    6    5    4    3    2    1
```

df2 is

```
    Vector1  Vector2
 1  AAA      a
 2  BBB      b
 3  CCC      e
 4  DDD      f
 5  EEE      k
 6  FFF      l
```

I would like to replace a variable name in df1 with the value of Vector2 in df2 when the variable name in df1 is identical to the value of Vector1 in df2.

So, ideally, I would like to get something like

```
     ZZZ  YYY  e    f    XXX  KKK
a    1    2    3    4    5    6
b    6    5    4    3    2    1
```

I have tried to modify the codes provided in [Match row names and column names to values in another data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41951418/match-row-names-and-column-names-to-values-in-another-data-frame). But, to me changing the name of an identified variable in df1 is somewhat challenging. Any suggestion or comment will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match` and `%in%` do the job. Try this:

```
## example 1
df1 <- t(data.frame(seq(1,6,by=1),seq(6,1,by=-1)))    
colnames(df1) <- c("ZZZ","YYY","CCC","DDD","XXX","KKK")    
rownames(df1) <- c("a","b")    
Vector1<-c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "FFF")
Vector2<-c("a", "b", "e", "f", "k", "l")
df2<-data.frame(cbind(Vector1, Vector2))

target <- match(colnames(df1), df2$Vector1, nomatch = 0)
colnames(df1)[colnames(df1) %in% df2$Vector1] <- as.character(df2$Vector2[target])
df1 # output
   ZZZ YYY e f XXX KKK
a   1   2 3 4   5   6
b   6   5 4 3   2   1

#example 2
df1 <- t(data.frame(seq(1,6,by=1),seq(6,1,by=-1)))
colnames(df1) <- c("ZZZ","YYY","CCC","DDD","XXX","KKK")
rownames(df1) <- c("a","b")
Vector1<-c("KKK", "BBB", "DDD", "XXX", "EEE", "FFF")
Vector2<-c("a", "b", "e", "f", "k", "l")
df2<-data.frame(cbind(Vector1, Vector2))

target <- match(colnames(df1), df2$Vector1, nomatch = 0)
colnames(df1)[colnames(df1) %in% df2$Vector1] <- as.character(df2$Vector2[target])
df1 # output
   ZZZ YYY CCC e f a
a   1   2   3 4 5 6
b   6   5   4 3 2 1
```

Comment: I really appreciate the comment. Your code is great, but I found that the original example of df1 ("AAA" "BBB" "CCC" "DDD" "EEE" "FFF") did not well represent my own data that I was looking into. So, I've updated df1. Sorry to bother you again, but would you please provide an updated comment?

Comment: Could you check your expected output and `df2`?

Comment: Ang, I am terribly sorry that I did not update the code for df2. I just updated, and when I ran your code, I encountered "Error in colnames(df1)[target] <- as.character(df2$Vector2[target]) : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments". Once again, thanks for your attention.

Comment: Regarding my expected output, what is presented in the question is what I want to get.

Comment: I edited my answer. To deal with `nomatch` cases, you just have to set as argument `nomatch = 0`

Comment: thanks. But, I found that your code does not work with the following datasets: 
df1 <- t(data.frame(seq(1,6,by=1),seq(6,1,by=-1)))    
colnames(df1) <- c("ZZZ","YYY","CCC","DDD","XXX","KKK")    
rownames(df1) <- c("a","b")    
Vector1<-c("KKK", "BBB", "DDD", "XXX", "EEE", "FFF")
Vector2<-c("a", "b", "e", "f", "k", "l")
df2<-data.frame(cbind(Vector1, Vector2))     Why does your code not work, and how to address it? Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry, `colnames(df1)[target]` is not relevent here. We need to use `colnames(df1)[colnames(df1) %in% df2$Vector1]` to select `colnames(df1)` that are in `df2$Vector1` and not to subset `colnames(df1)` based on `target` as I have done. In you example it works fine because matched values were at the same positions (third and fourth) in `df1` and `df2`. I will edit my answer